# How can I use a different color to fill the left side of the input[type="range"] in chrome using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, slider

As you can see below in IE the slider is working, but I can't find what is the "ms-fill-lower" pseudo-code in chrome/firefox. Also I haven't figured out how can I print out the number continously above the thumb (I was thinking about creating a new childnode in JS and then using the position of the slider + the current value of the thumb and with this info I could create a new position for the brand new childnode. Is there an easier way maybe?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE:html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input {
      position: fixed;
      top: 40;
      right: 40;
    }
    
    input[type=range] {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin: 30px 0px;
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    input[type=range]:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
    
    input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #ffccff, 0px 0px 0px #ffccff;
     
      height: 30px;
      width: 48px;
      background-image: url('https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/12204684_1096899726988871_1886399559_n.jpg?oh=b8481694391b1a5ebe58733f0638a08f&oe=563669C2');
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
    input[type=range]::-ms-track {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      animate: 0.2s;
      background: transparent;
      border-color: transparent;
     color: transparent;
    }
    
    input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
      background: #ff0000;
      border: 0.2px solid #ff0000;
       }
    
    input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
      background: #ffccff;
     
       }
    
    input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
      background: #ff0000;
    }
    
    input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
      background: #ffccff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="range"></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo elements for chrome `::-webkit-slider-thumb` and `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track`
for firefox `::-moz-range-thumb` and `::-moz-range-track`
to print the number continuously

```
<input type="range" max="22" min="12" value="18" step="2" oninput="dataUpdate()" id="myInput" />
<p id="mydata"></p>

<script>
 function dataUpdate(){
   var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
   document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML=x;
 }
</script>
```

where `value` is current position of the range on load, `step` is the difference between each value, `oninput` event will trigger when you'll move the range's thumb and the output will be displayed in the `<p>` tag

to check pseudo elements in chrome you can read this http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-shadow-dom/